# Converting Python Dictionary to 3D Matlab Matrix

Tags: python, arrays, matlab, numpy, dictionary

I have the following dictionary `results_dict` in Python 3.2 where the key field is a string value and the value field is a list of 3 arrays. Each array has 400 float values. I want to convert this dictionary into a data structure that can be used in Matlab 2017b. However, if I execute the following:

`savemat('GridCellResults.mat', results_dict, oned_as='row');`

The command executes successfully but Matlab is not able to understand the matrix file. For this reason, I wrote the following code to convert the previous dictionary into a 3 Dimensional Matrix (X,Y,Z) where X is the size of the array (400 Elements) and Y is the number of arrays for each dictionary key (3 Arrays) and Z is the number of elements in the dictionary. However, when I execute the code below I get the following error:

`IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices`

Here is the code. Any clue why I am getting this error. Also even if I try without the transpose function i keep getting the same error.

```
import numpy as np

CARDINALITY = 400            # Number of angular domain values.
NUM_COLUMNS = 3
NUM_CELLS = 114

matlab_array =  np.zeros((CARDINALITY, NUM_COLUMNS, NUM_CELLS))

for key, value in results_dict.items():   
    matlab_array[:, 0, key] = np.transpose(value[0])
    matlab_array[:, 1, key] = np.transpose(value[1])
    matlab_array[:, 2, key] = np.transpose(value[2])
```

Comment: It is because you can not use strings as indices in arrays.Try running an integer counter in your for loop and use it as the last index instead of key.

You can convert you dictionary to an `collections.OrderedDict` if you want to make sure you can access the elements in the same order.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to follow your description, I can successfully write and read such a dictionary

In an ipython session:

```
In [48]: from scipy.io import savemat, loadmat
In [49]: adict = {'a':[np.arange(3),np.ones(3),np.array([4,2,1])]}
In [50]: adict['b'] = [np.arange(3),np.ones(3),np.array([4,2,1])]
In [51]: adict
Out[51]: 
{'a': [array([0, 1, 2]), array([1., 1., 1.]), array([4, 2, 1])],
 'b': [array([0, 1, 2]), array([1., 1., 1.]), array([4, 2, 1])]}
In [52]: pwd
Out[52]: '/home/paul/mypy'
In [53]: savemat('stack48385062.mat',adict, oned_as='row')
In [54]: data = loadmat('stack48385062.mat')
In [55]: data
Out[55]: 
{'__globals__': [],
 '__header__': b'MATLAB 5.0 MAT-file Platform: posix, Created on: Mon Jan 22 09:15:31 2018',
 '__version__': '1.0',
 'a': array([[0., 1., 2.],
        [1., 1., 1.],
        [4., 2., 1.]]),
 'b': array([[0., 1., 2.],
        [1., 1., 1.],
        [4., 2., 1.]])}
```

The lists of arrays (of constant size) were converted to 2d arrays.

In an Octave session:

```
>> load stack48385062.mat
>> a
a =
   0   1   2
   1   1   1
   4   2   1
>> b
b =
   0   1   2
   1   1   1
   4   2   1
>>
```

---

Or creating your 3d array (using a numeric index rather than string key):

```
In [56]: M=np.zeros([3, 3, 2])
In [57]: for i in range(len(adict)):
    ...:     for j in range(3):
    ...:         v = adict[list(adict.keys())[i]]
    ...:         M[:, j, i] = v[j]
    ...:         
In [58]: M
Out[58]: 
array([[[0., 0.],
        [1., 1.],
        [4., 4.]],

       [[1., 1.],
        [1., 1.],
        [2., 2.]],

       [[2., 2.],
        [1., 1.],
        [1., 1.]]])

>> load stack48385062_1.mat
>> M
M =
ans(:,:,1) =
   0   1   4
   1   1   2
   2   1   1
ans(:,:,2) =
   0   1   4
   1   1   2
   2   1   1
```

I should have made the initial dictionary with  a list of 3 of 4 element arrays, so it would be easier to track track transpositions.  MATLAB and numpy have different axis orders, which can be confusing.  `savemat` tries to compensate.